# Is there a quick way to import my external css files so that I can convert my dynamic webpage into a static one?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and I want to be able to make one of the pages 'standalone' html so that I can display it in a browser that's not connected to the internet. Any ideas?

Comment: CTRL+S will save the page. Is not that enough?

Comment: For a single page, just save page / complete. However, if you plan to save the whole site and its dynamically generated content, you will need wamp or similar

Comment: Thanks for the tip re. CTRL+S ... it enabled me to see quite a lot of the page 'standalone'. I'll fiddle around with wamp to see if I can get more. The CTRL+S seems to ignore my .js and .css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a local copy of your actual page view user Ctrl+s. This will not include all css/js and might be not what you want. Its a better screenshot.

To get a fully working local version install xampp to get a webserver and a mysql server.
https://www.apachefriends.org/

Download you WordPress instance and move it in the htdocs directory that is inside the xampp installation.

Create a mysqldump of your wordpress database and load it into your local mysqlserver.

Configure your local WordPress instance so it can connect to the database.

Comment: Thank you so much Marcus. I will follow your guidance. Extremely helpful. Encouraging for me too, as I'm a new member to the community and got my wrist slapped twice! I appreciate you taking the time out to address my question in such detail and would upvote your response if I could. > Just a quick note, I understand that doing the above re wamp etc. will enable me to get a fully working site on my local pc, but do you know if I will then be able to generate one static html file from that (my site only has one page)?